# How do I bypass the Verizon activation on a Samsung Fascinate?

Tags: samsung-fascinate, activation

I want to use a Samsung Fascinate (model SCH-I500) in WiFi only mode for development and testing purposes. The device has been factory reset and boots to the Verizon activation screen. How do I bypass activation? Do I need to root the device?

Comment: You used to be able to bypass the activation screen by tapping in all four corners of the screen (start in the top left and work clockwise from there). Don't know if it still works, but you could try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some additional research I finally came across a [YouTube video on how to bypass a Samsung Galaxy S Continuum activation screen](http://youtu.be/4R6lWVAIY7E). The steps outlined in the video are very simple:

1. From the Activation Screen select Emergency call.
2. Enter the following `*#83786633` (`*#TESTMODE`) which will disappear when you press the last 3
3. A toast with the text `Softkey is enabled` will appear
4. Then press the home button

Answer (score 1):

Emergency, dial: *#83786633 and a message will pop up saying "Softkey is enabled" then press the home key.

Answer (score 0):

Install a stock or a custom ROM that best fits your need from, e.g., [Samobile](http://www.sammobile.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=48) or [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=748). This way you can select the android version and its flavor.