# Verizon Activation Setup Galaxy s3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, verizon, activation

I recently bought a new contract-free Verizon CDMA Samsung Galaxy S3 for testing purpose and I couldn't pass the activation setup wizard. When I reached the customer service they said I have to activate it to use it which is lame. I buy a 300$ phone and they force me to activate it with a plan to use it. How can I skip this?

I tried [how-do-i-bypass-the-verizon-activation-on-a-samsung-fascinate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42421/how-do-i-bypass-the-verizon-activation-on-a-samsung-fascinate) but it didnt work.

Comment: Might not be the answer you were hoping for: But I'd return such a "brick" immediately and have my money back. Tampering with the device might just void that chance. If they didn't tell you about that restriction when you bought it, it's their fault: you can argue they knowingly sold you something you cannot use.

Comment: @Izzy Yup You are right!! Business tactics. It is my company mobile. Some how I activated that phone with with prepaid plan and didn't pay anything and successfully able to use it in wifi.

Comment: Looks like that's a solution: liberal pricing (get the cheapest prepaid, throw away when empty), liberal effort (instead of days for googling etc.). Do you count it such? Then make it an answer, and accept it (as soon as it's due for that: AFAIR you can accept your own answer after ~48h earliest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I activated that phone with a prepaid plan and didn't pay anything and successfully able to use it in wifi.