# Remove Samsung Tab S3 SetupWizard Message 'Activation Incomplete' for Verizon service

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab, verizon, activation, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

I just purchased a used Samsung Tab S3 which comes with Verizon network capabilities. I don't want to use cell capabilities, just Wifi.

After setup, on the lock screen and in the notification center is a message from "Setup Wizard" that says "Activation Incomplete" and to call Verizon support to activate the device (which I don't want to do).

Is there a way to remove this message without calling Verizon?

Comment: Have you [removed the SIM card?](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-212513/) Alternatively have you seen: [How do I bypass the Verizon activation on a Samsung Fascinate?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42421/3573)

Comment: I did see that post about bypassing activation, but that's during initial setup, which I'm well past. I tried removing the SIM card and now the notification has changed to "No SIM card inserted", which also won't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an incomplete solution, since the notification itself says "These notifications can't be turned off":

1. Touch and hold on the notification in the notifications dropdown
2. Tap "Details"
3. When "System UI" opens under "App notifications" in Settings, it will briefly flash the "Ongoing" section
4. Tap the "Ongoing" section
5. Tap "Notification Style"
6. Tap "Silent and minimized"
7. Tap "App icon badges" to turn the switch off

This makes the notification much smaller in the notification dropdown, and doesn't show the icon in the notification bar

This works as of 2020-04-24 13:20 CDT on Android 9